# Vector space can be written as direct sum of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove that all vector spaces can be written as the direct sum of two subspaces.

My attempt: If each vector in vector space V can be uniquely written as the sum of two other vectors in V, the two vectors can be categorized into subspaces and thus V can be written as the direct sum of these subspaces. I am not sure how to show that this is true for all cases though.

**Edit**
Sorry for the confusion,
to clarify I meant
Given a vector space V with a subspace W, prove that there exists a subspace W' such that the direct sum of W and W' is V.
I am not sure about my proof method at all. Thank you.

Comment: Is this true if the dimension is one?

Comment: Well, you can always write $V=V+\{0\}$, a trivial decomposition.

Comment: What you've written doesn't make sense. Why should we be able to write a vector uniquely as the sum of two other vectors?

Comment: @ElliotG Isn't that a property of closure under addition of vectorspaces

Answer (score 6):

Let $\mathcal Z$ be the set of subspaces of $V$ that have trivial intersection with $W$. $\mathcal Z$ is partially ordered by $\subseteq$. One verifies that Zorn's lemma applies, so let $W'$ be a maximal element of $\mathcal Z$.
Clearly, $W\cap W'=\{0\}$. And if we assume $v\notin W+W'$, then $\langle W',v\rangle$ still has trivial intersection with $W$, contradicting maximality of $W'$. Hence $V=W\oplus W'$.